# Big execution time for a simple request with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a weird behaviour from Entity Framework 6. I have a simple (a simple where and a simple select) query which takes 30s.

I used Sql Profiler to watch what sql code is executed. I am using a Where then the FirstOrDefault method to get an item. Then I tried another query, I did a ToList (to fetch data) then FirstOrDefault and it takes less than 1 second.

```
Original code (takes 30s to be executed):
-----------------------------------------

id = Container.SocialNetworks.Where(a => a.SocialNetwork == EnumSocialNetwork.LinkedIn && a.Link == linkedinurl && a.User.TenantID == Container.TenantId).Select(i => i.UserID).FirstOrDefault();

From SQL Profiler :
-------------------

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Limit1].[UserID] AS [UserID]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID]
        FROM  [dbo].[SocialNetworks] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UserID] = [Extent2].[ID]
        WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[SocialNetwork]) AND (([Extent1].[Link] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[Link] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Extent2].[TenantID] = @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0=N'linkedin.com/in/a-profile',@p__linq__1=5

After testing another solutions (takes less than 1s):
-----------------------------------------------------

id = Container.SocialNetworks.Where(a => a.SocialNetwork == EnumSocialNetwork.LinkedIn && a.Link == linkedinurl && a.User.TenantID == Container.TenantId).Select(i => i.UserID).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

From SQL Profiler:
------------------

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID]
    FROM  [dbo].[SocialNetworks] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UserID] = [Extent2].[ID]
    WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[SocialNetwork]) AND (([Extent1].[Link] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[Link] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ([Extent2].[TenantID] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0=N'linkedin.com/in/a-profile-as',@p__linq__1=5
```

As you can see, I use ToList to fetch data before filtering with FirstOrDefault. And, normally, it is not advisable to do a ToList, a eager load. Why Entity Framework put a select into a select when I use FirstOrDefault ?

I am sorry for my english and I hope I explained properly my issue.

**EDIT :**

I have something interesting to add, when the "linkedinurl" value does not exist, and only when it does not exist, in the database, both queries take less than 1 second.

**EDIT 2:**

After writing a comment, I would like to add that our database is on Azure. And the problem does not appear on a simple SQLEXPRESS database. Moreover, this issue appeared like 4 or 5 days ago.

Comment: Your second query should have taken more time than the first one because its loading all the data into memory and then taking the one. It looks too weird. Are you sure that first query is taking more time?

Comment: If you only read data, You should use AsNoTracking()

Comment: @OfficalMesut that'ss the other thing! Issue is why first query is taking so much time as the OP said?

Comment: Really, I can assure you that the first example takes 30s (with a single FirstOrDefault, without the ToList)...I that's why it's weird ! And AsNoTracking allows me to fetch the Id ?

Comment: Do you run these queries consequently in single application run? Have you tried to run queries separately in 2 application runs? And also you can try to run in reversed order and see what happens.

Comment: A pure LinQ solution may be the best answer here, remember it goes like `from tableName t in db.TableName select thisColumn where t.var == var`

Comment: @Alexander I tried your stuff. When I do the "only FirstOrDefault" then "ToList().FirstOrDefault()", I have 27s and 51ms. In reversed order, a little bit less than 1s for the ToList and 15s for the "only FirstOrDefault".

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/why-does-adding-a-top-1-dramatically-worsen-performance

Comment: @Alexander Sorry I didn't see your comment but I understand that TOP 1 can slow a query but anyway, we got a lots of FirstOrDefault (with a join) in all our code and first time we see that. And I checked the SocialNetwork model and table and there is nothing weird or different from other tables...And, the weirdest thing is this issue appeared recently and we didn't update any nuget package, the model didn't change. The only thing I can add, is that our database is on Azure and we have not this problem on a SQLEXPRESS database.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you use `FirstOrDefault` AFTER the `where().Select()` combination.

The first query would work better like this :

```
id = Container.SocialNetworks.FirstOrDefault(a => a.SocialNetwork == EnumSocialNetwork.LinkedIn && a.Link == linkedinurl && a.User.TenantID == Container.TenantId)?.UserID;
```

As you can see, I use `FirstOrDefault` just like you used your `Where`, but this will load the entire object, as discussed in the comments.

Why is your seconde query faster ? Because you ended the query with a `ToList()` so the `FirstOrDefault` part apply only in your c# code, AFTER the lines have been loaded, not on the DB with a double select.

**Edit :**

Trying these 2 lines might highlight the root cause better :

**1. Try to order your set :**

```
id = Container.SocialNetworks
   .Where(a => a.SocialNetwork == EnumSocialNetwork.LinkedIn && a.Link == linkedinurl && a.User.TenantID == Container.TenantId)
   .OrderBy(t => t.UserID).Select(i => i.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
```

**2. Use an aggregate function :**

```
id = Container.SocialNetworks
    .Where(a => a.SocialNetwork == EnumSocialNetwork.LinkedIn && a.Link == linkedinurl && a.User.TenantID == Container.TenantId)
    .Min(i => i.UserID);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanation but when you use FirstOrDefault, you can't select a single column after. I tried your line of code and it can't compile because, FirstOrDefault does not return a IQueryable but the entire Object (T).

Comment: it should be `id = Container.SocialNetworks.Select(i => i.UserID).FirstOrDefault(a => a.SocialNetwork == EnumSocialNetwork.LinkedIn && a.Link == linkedinurl && a.User.TenantID == Container.TenantId);`

Comment: Sorry but, I can't filter query after a Select of an integer. Because it returns a IQueryable<int>.

Comment: There is no difference between `collection.Where(predicate).First()` and `collection.First(predicate)`.

Comment: Sorry sorry, you select only one thing, it's even simpler, look at my edit

Comment: But I don't want to load the entire object just for a simple integer (the id).

Comment: And the problem with you solution is that you will load whole entity and not only `UserId` as author does.

Comment: Well... Still better than the original 30 secondes query, but not perfect. And the rest of my answer makes sens... Your seconde query seems like a good way to go for me... As long as you know why the first one is too long. I just can't think of any miracle here

Comment: @Toben Thank you for that interesting problem, a better answer than mine would also serve me good.

Comment: I understand your answer @AntoinePelletier but we have more and more users coming and we really can't ignore "eager loading". And thank you, I hope someone will have a genius idea

Comment: @Toben I edited to add the LinQ thing, but I think it will be the equivalent of your first query, not sure, you might want to try it.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Thank you a lot but no...Linq does the same result (~30s execution time)

Comment: @Toben I updated my answer one last time. I hope you will be able to solve your problem using one of those. Cheers !

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Thank you for your code but...For the first one, I got the same amount of time and for the second one, I got an exception because there is no result so it can't return me a "Min"

Comment: Yes, the second solution works only if there is at least one line respecting the condition.

Comment: @Toben You could use `Min()` even in your case, but you'll have to check before querying IF there is any data corresponding by using `.Any()` function. Then again, it's like : "One query to check the existence of the row, if the row exist, select Min". So in case there are datas, it's like querying two time.